# Do I need to be permitted by the Pandas Official when I want to translate Pandas User Guide into Chinese ? And how can I get in touch with them?

Tags: pandas

I'm a quant from China, and when I come to manipulating high dimension data, I started to read Pandas User Guide for more detials and help.
I found that nobody ever translated the User Guide of Pandas into Chinese before, but I believe that it will help if I translate it myself.
The problem is, if I want to post the Chinese version of Pandas User Guide on CSDN ( like a Chinese StackOverflow ), is it legal? Or how can I get in touch with Pandas Official?
Great thx!
Here's some part of my translation

My plan is to translate the User Guide step by step, when I need to use some of the part, I will translate them first.

[image]

Is translating the Pandas User Guide myself legal?
Is posting the Chinese version User Guide on CSDN (not for business) legal?
How can I get in touch with the Pandas Official ( email address for best )?
Thx!

Answer (score 1):

Pandas is released under a permissive BSD license, so you do not need to request permission to modify/translate it and distribute it as long as you give proper credit and references and publish the changes under the same license.

However, it makes more sense to do this as an integrated contribution, for this you can follow the [guidelines on how to contribute to the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/development/contributing_documentation.html).

To contact the developers you can use the [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/g/pydata) or use the [GitHub tracker](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues).

Comment: Great thx! I fully understand now, thanks for your kind reconmendation.